# Finding out angle for Triangle with a Parallelogram inside of it?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a triangle with $\theta$ between $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$. The opposite side has to be at least $4.2$ m and middle has to be $2.6$ m. How do I define the opposite side?[image]

Comment: what do you mean with middle?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The 2.6m.

Answer (score 1):

The two triangles are similiar, so the side form the point where $\theta$ is to the insection with the opposite side is equal to 4.2/2.6w=1.615w.

Now we have $$\frac{\text{opposite side}}{1.615w} = \tan(\theta)$$

Thus $\text{opposite side} = 1.615w\tan(\theta)$